# CMake: timestamp in localization format

Tags: cmake, timestamp, locale

Colleagues, can you please tell me if it is possible to receive TIMESTAMP in CMake in localization format and in localization language?

I have not found such options for string(TIMESTAMP).

Comment: Why would you want your build system to have different timestamp formatting based on the language settings of the build machine?  What do you plan to use this string for?

Comment: If the answer to your question as a whole - it is because at my home I use to speak, read and write my native language. (I apologize in advance to anyone who doesn't like this.) My native language is convenient and comfortable for me, with all due respect to English, which I was forced to learn from childhood.
If answer your question in particular, it is because the local date and time are passed as arguments to a text pre-processor that processes non-English text.

Forgive me for some tactlessness  - but do you know the answer to my question? Or are you just satisfying your curiosity?

Comment: `not found such options for string(TIMESTAMP)` but there is `<format_string>` that you can set to your `%b %Y...` that you want to. Looks like cmake uses `strftime`, but it checks which [specifiers are allowed](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmTimestamp.cxx#L190) so `%c` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to receive TIMESTAMP in CMake in localization format and in localization language?

No, cmake `string(TIMESTAMP <format_string` does not allow `%c` `strftime` specifier. Because `%c` is required in `strftime` [in C99](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.3.5) I believe the only change needed in cmake sources to support it is to add `case 'c':` in [cmTimestamp.cxx](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/cmTimestamp.cxx#L150). I think you could also call `locale d_t_fmt` and pass the result to `string(TIMESTAMP "${the_result}"`.

Just use an external program. On linux you would just call `date` with `execute_process` and capture it's output.